# Cross-domain ajax request basic authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I'm making cross-domain ajax request to get some data. The REST service have `Basic authentication` (set through `IIS`).

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            data: myData,
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/MyService/MyService.svc/GetData",
            success: function (jsonData) {
                console.log(jsonData);
            },
            error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

When I make this request, it prompts me to enter credentials & I have to manually enter credentials to get the response. Can we send those credentials through the request itself?

Answer (score 6):

Pass username and password like following code,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/javascript",
    data: myData,
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/MyService/MyService.svc/GetData",
    success: function (jsonData) {
        console.log(jsonData);
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
    username: username,
    password: password,
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'yoururl',
    username : username,
    password :password,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    dataType: "text",
    xhrFields: 
    {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));             
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not excited about this answer, and here's why: it's redundant (question was answered about a half-year earlier) and it's redundant (jQuery handles the auth stuff for you, AFAICT). If I'm wrong about the latter, edit the answer, and I'll delete this comment.

Comment: Using the beforeSend property worked for me, since username and password for some reason weren't adding the Authorization header. Just in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({//No need to pass credentials 
            type: "get",
            async: false,
            url: "https://someurl/",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },            
            success: function (data) {
                //do something
            }
        })
```