# Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cors, sap-basis

We have some web services returning xml+atom response. These are hosted on SAP NetWeaver Gateway application server. They require BASIC authentication to access them. The response contains the following headers to support CORS:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
access-control-max-age: 1728000
```

We have an HTML5 app which uses jquery to call the service as below:

```
var url = "http://mytesturl.com/test/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: true,
        contentType:"application/atom+xml", 
        type: "GET",
        crossdomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(uname, passwd));
        }
    })
            .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){alert("success");})
       .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log(jqXHR.status);
            alert(errorThrown + jqXHR.status);
        });
```

Despite the headers coming in the server response, we continue to get the CORS errors as below:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The username (uname) and password (passwd) are correct. If I try calling the service using a tool like RestClient, I can see the headers in the response. I have tried testing in Chrome version 31.0 and Safari version 6.0.5. I am not sure what is missing. Any suggestions to help resolve the issue would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: The `contentType` option sets the `Content-type` header of the ***request body***, *not* the response body.  I don't see you sending any data, so that option is incorrect.

Comment: worth a look -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689496/cross-domain-ajax-request-basic-authentication

Comment: The issue might have to do with the `401` error.  The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is probably only sent when the server responds with `200 OK`, not `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: We added this 401 and added the headers as the answer below. Post this, when the client makes an HTTP GET request, I can see an HTTP OPTIONS call happen. The OPTIONS call returns status 204 No data and it does not contain the access control headers in the response. The GET call never happens. Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to include the `Authorization` header in the list of allowed headers:

```
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, Authorization
```

Your client code is sending an `Authorization` header (the Basic authentication stuff), so the server must explicitly allow this at the CORS level.

Also ensure that the server is actually responding with those headers for an `OPTIONS` verb request from the client.

Comment: We added this header. Post this, when the client makes an HTTP GET request, I can see an HTTP OPTIONS call happen. The OPTIONS call returns status 204 No data and it does not contain the access control headers in the response. The GET call never happens. Any ideas to fix this?