# JQuery $.post cross domain and credentials

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I have written a web application which uses lot's of `$.post` calls with JQuery. Now I would like to send `withCredentials: true` with it to keep a session alive, what looks like this in `$.ajax` (and also works like this):

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://example.com/server/api.php',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            data: {
                username : 'test',
                password : 'test'
            },
            success: function (d) {
                $('body').html(d.status);
            }
        });
```

This is because I would now like to upload the PHP files to my server and export the client side using Cordova. (`withCredentials: true` is only included because of testing on my localhost server)
Can I pack this into the `$.post` call or do I need to replace all calls? (I would write a new function which would look similar to $.post)

Comment: and the question is ??

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689496/cross-domain-ajax-request-basic-authentication

Comment: @ZeeTee linking to a question that has no marked correct answer is mean :P

Comment: Look at the first answer, it clearly shows the answer.

Comment: @ZeeTee This is not a duplicate as for I want session credentials and the other thread wants basic authentication

Comment: If you want session credentials you need to pass cookies, which I'm pretty sure jQuery does by default.

Comment: @ZeeTee Nope, to I need to pass `withCredentials: true` for it to respond to me with the session (works in my test file)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) to set default options that each ajax request will use (including `$.post` and `$.get`)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test'
});

$.post('http://example.com/server/api.php', {
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test'
}, function (d) {
    $('body').html(d.status);
}, 'json');
```

---

Also the warning regarding this API

> Note: The settings specified here will affect all calls to $.ajax or
>   Ajax-based derivatives such as $.get(). This can cause undesirable
>   behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting
>   the normal default settings. For that reason we strongly recommend
>   against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the
>   call or define a simple plugin to do so.

*from jQuery documentation*

Comment: I already tried this, now it works though because I placed it at the end of the file and not at the beginning

Comment: what about access to https requests, that require keys to access?

Comment: @RicardoMota do you mean with a client certificate? I don't think there's a way to do that yet